# Where is the best place to re-learn graphics programming

Tags: silverlight, graphics

Thinking in regards to Sliverlight, I would like to know where would be good places to go to get a refresher on 3d space, transforms, matrix manipulation, and all that good stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I may have found it myself.  Was looking at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189037(VS.95).aspx
and
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/TransformswithGDIplus09142005064919AM/TransformswithGDIplus.aspx

Comment: Your question specified 3D, this is all 2D.

Comment: You found your answer in 2 minutes. Next time you might want to search before asking lol

Comment: 3D is just a part of it.  But also want the 2D stuff

Answer (score 8):

There's always *The Bible*

[image: Foley & van Dam]

It *is* expensive and very heavy on the theory, so there's also the cheaper *Bible Lite*

[image]

As pointed out in some comments and additional answers, it is definitely worth noting that this book is now quite dated. However, in the context of the original question, there's not really been any change in the low-level principles of linear algebra in a seriously long time.

If you are looking to learn about high-level graphics programming this may well not be the first book for you. But if you like to know about "the guts-of-the-machine" and the underlying maths -- perhaps you are the kind of person that thinks folk should learn C :-) -- then go nuts.

Comment: Absolutely, can't beat the Foley and van Dam and some other guys that gave a few opinions...

Comment: although it is quite dated by now.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a place, but I've found [3D Programming for Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/3D/) by Charles Petzold excellent.  It covers everything you ask about and is focused specifically on WPF/silverlight.

Of course Petzold (as usual) is able to communicate the important concepts beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Free graphics algorithms can be found in the 
[comp.graphics.algorithms faq](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/algorithms-faq/)

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned you should really learn linear algebra, here are some great video lectures about it, [MIT Linear Alebgra Video Lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Mathematics/18-06Spring-2005/VideoLectures/).

Answer (score 0):

Any linear algebra textbook should provide the math refresher; there's a fairly good one available online at [Linear Algebra textbook home page](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that although the bible (by Foley & Van Damn that is) was the greatest book for its time, but it is somewhat outdated.

I would suggest '**Advanced animation & Rendering techniques**' by Alan and Mark Watt. 
The only problem with this book is that it gives you a good understanding almost about every broad aspect in CG but it assumes you have some familiarity with it, and does not explain it all the way.
You can always have a look in the Bib and find enhanced articles and books about each subject you are interested in depth.

If you want further on once you have more understanding, or if you want to dive into the world of computer graphics and the use of GPU I suggest to have a look at the three 'GPU Gems'.